# URL redirect with params in Nginx

Tags: redirect, nginx, url-rewriting

In [nginx](/questions/tagged/nginx), I am redirecting a URL with a param  like:

`www.example.com/watch?v=12345678` -> `www.example.com?vid=12345678`

So I wrote the following configuration for the same:

```
location  /watch {
    if ($args ~* v=(.*)) {
        set $args vid=$1;
        rewrite ^/watch?(.*)$ / redirect; 
    }
}
```

Everything is working as expected. But here I have few queries:

- Is it possible to implement it without using if condition (I tried but failed)
- how to rewrite redirect without using set (Please ref: http://lethain.com/rewriting-parameterized-urls-with-nginx/)
- Is it good method for SEO? if not then how it can be achieved?
- Any other better alternative for the above redirection in [nginx](/questions/tagged/nginx)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have nothing better than:

```
location /watch {
    return 302 $scheme://$host?vid=$arg_v;
}
```

It avoids using `if` and `rewrite`, which is always a good thing. If you need to check for `v=` in the URI, then use `if`, but rather test whether `$arg_v` is empty.

However it redirects even if there is no argument or if it is empty. I guess you should filter those case out of the redirected location.

From a SEO prospective, I do not see any difference. I would avoid serving any URI with arguments, though. I would prefer URIs like `example.com/video/123456`

Comment: you are right. Here in return, is there any need of 'continue'?

Comment: Sorry for my typo mistake. I want to reference 'break' here. check this: nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html. Is it required here?

Comment: You are talking about `return` and quoting the documentation for `rewrite`... Read http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#return and http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite

Comment: As you suggested URL like: example.com/video/123456 .. How to achieve this?

Comment: I do not think it is that different from what you already achieved. Try to think by yourself... :o\ You will learn more that way than if everything is cooked for you